# fwrite in android sometimes very slow

Tags: c, java-native-interface

I was using fwrite to write a buffer (the size is 460800) to disk in android jni，in most times it cost about 10-40ms,and this is acceptable, but in sometimes, it will cost 500--800ms, that is to slow and I can't accept this.

Is anyOne known that why this happens? And how to solve this question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Occassionally, the internal buffer kept in the `FILE` you write to is flushed to the operating system. Occassionally, the operating system flushes data it keeps in its internal cache onto the flash memory you are writing to. Flash memory is slow, so if you are writing more than the memory can handle, you have to wait. There is no way around this waiting if you want to have the data end up on the flash memory.

Comment: thank you for this answer, I called fflush after fwrite everytime. is that mean everytime it will write the buffer to real disk file?

Comment: @vaiRonaldo Yes. `fflush()` causes exactly that to happen. If you don't want to wait very long every time, consider writing smaller amounts of data at a time and don't call `fflush()` as often.

Comment: @vaiRonaldo if you are writing to a file on flash, there is no disk.  The characteristics of the underlying physical medium are not like a disk.  Erasing and writing a flash page takes a long time, and there's no way round that.

Comment: @Martin James If write size is a multiple of flash page size (and on page boundaries), at least repetitive partial page updates can be avoided.

Comment: @MartinJames I am wirting to android sdcard, it is a flash or disk? What's the difference between flash and disk?